# Cannot get values from splitted Array String into a String

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I am trying to get the values out of String[] value; into String lastName;, but I get errors and it says `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at arduinojava.OpenFile.openCsv(OpenFile.java:51) (lastName = value[2];)`. Here is my code, but I am not sure if it is going wrong at the split() or declaring the variables or getting the data into another variable.

Also I am calling input.next(); three times for ignoring first row, because otherwise `of study` of `Field of study` would also be printed out..

The rows I am trying to share are in a .csv file:

```
University  Firstname   Lastname    Field of study
Karlsruhe   Jerone          L           Software Engineering 
Amsterdam   Shahin          S           Software Engineering 
Mannheim    Saman           K           Artificial Intelligence
Furtwangen  Omid            K           Technical Computing
Esslingen   Cherelle        P           Technical Computing
```

Here's my code:

```
// Declare Variable
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
//    StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
String data = "";
int rowCounter = 0;
String delimiter = ";";
String[] value;
String lastName = "";

/**
* Opencsv csv (comma-seperated values) reader
*/
public void openCsv() throws Exception {

    if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        // Get file
        File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

        // Create a scanner for the file
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

        // Ignore first row
        input.next();
        input.next();
        input.next();

        // Read from input
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            // Gets whole row
            //                data.append(rowCounter + " " + input.nextLine() + "\n");
            data = input.nextLine();
            // Split row data
            value = data.split(String.valueOf(delimiter));
            lastName = value[2];
            rowCounter++;
            System.out.println(rowCounter + " " + data + "Lastname: " + lastName);
        }
        input.close();
        } else {
        sb.append("No file was selected");
    }
}
```

Comment: Share the line that you are trying to split. check the `length` before get any value from an array. Why are you doing in this way `data.split(String.valueOf(delimiter))`. Simply use `data.split(delimiter)`

Comment: Looks like there is one line without an `lastname`

Comment: comment ignore first row  but you are calling `input.next();` three times. why?

Comment: You're splitting each line by the `;` character, but your sample data contains no `;`s.

Comment: Added the rows I am trying to split, also if I only call input.next() one time, for ignoring first row, `of study` will also be printed for some strange reason. will add the ; in the csv

Comment: Your `Scanner` is splitting on whitespace by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lines are separated by spaces not by semicolon as per your sample. Try in this way to split based on one or more spaces.

```
data.split("\\s+");
```

Change the delimiter as shown below:

```
String delimiter = "\\s+";
```

---

#### EDIT

The CSV file should be in this format. All the values should be enclosed inside double quotes and there should be a valid separator like comma,space,semicolon etc.

```
"University"  "Firstname" "Lastname"     "Field of study"
"Karlsruhe"   "Jerone"        "L"       "Software Engineering" 
"Amsterdam"   "Shahin"        "S"       "Software Engineering"
```

Comment: Tried it right now, same error.. at line 51 = `lastName = value[2];`

Comment: check the length first before getting the data from array. What is the length of the array after splitting as I suggested it in my previous comments.

Comment: `data.split(String.valueOf(delimiter))` because I found it somewhere on stackoverflow. The array length is 6 `sizeArray = value.length;`

Comment: It might help you [How to read and parse CSV file in Java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/)

Comment: Thanks, will follow that one, maybe the tutorial I am following is outdated or wrong or something. Will come back if it does or not work

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you file is using delimiter as ';' if not add it and try it again, it should work!!

Comment: Whenever I print out everything from `data` it has ';' between everything by itself, I also tried adding ';' to it, now it prints this between everything ;";";

Comment: University;Firstname;Lastname;Field of study
Karlsruhe;Jerone;L;Software Engineering 


your input csv should look like this

and you are printing data directly into output sop so it will have ; seperated data

Comment: value = data.split(String.valueOf(delimiter));

instead try 

value = data.split(delimiter);

Answer (score 0):

Use [OpenCSV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/files/opencsv) Library for read CSV files .[Here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-csv-file/) is a detailed example on read/write CSV files using java by Viral Patel